# Is there a way to unbind multiple bound keys simultaneously in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that `root.bind('keyname', function)` will bind a key to a function and `root.unbind('keyname')` will unbind a key that was previously bound, but is there a way to unbind every key at once? If I have many keys that are bound, and I want to unbind them all, do I have to manually type all of the `unbind` statements or is there a method to do all of that in one line or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, calling bind with no arguments returns a list of all bound events.

```
for key in root.bind():
    root.unbind(key)
```